# Pagination issue: First & Previous Buttons not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing **Simple Visualforce Pagination Example Using Standaredset Controller.**. In this example, Next and Last works fine, but Previous and First doesn't works as expected. Whats the issue ?

**OpportunityListCon**

```
public class OpportunityListCon {
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        set;
        get{
            if(setCon == null){
                String query = 'select Name, Account.Name,Description,closedate from Opportunity';
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
    }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities(){
        setCon.setPageSize(5);
        return (List<Opportunity>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

**OpportunityListConVFPage:**

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityListCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="opp">
                <apex:column value="{!opp.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.closedate}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Description}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:commandButton reRender="{!setCon.hasPrevious}" value="First" action="{!setCon.first}" />
            <apex:commandButton reRender="{!setCon.hasPrevious}" value="Previous" action="{!setCon.previous}" />
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize) < setCon.ResultSize}"
                             value="{!setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize} Of {!setCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize) >= setCon.ResultSize}"
                             value="{!setCon.ResultSize} Of {!setCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setCon.hasNext}" value="Next" action="{!setCon.next}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setCon.hasNext}" value="Last" action="{!setCon.last}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to check `reRender="{!setCon.hasPrevious}"`. Try without that, it should work. I tested this, its working

Add below in `OpportunityListCon`

```
//Page Navigation buttons
    public void mf(){
        setcon.first();
    }
    public void mn(){
        setcon.next();
    }
    public void mp(){
        setcon.previous();
    }
    public void ml(){
        setcon.last();
    }
```

and then use below

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityListCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="opp">
                <apex:column value="{!opp.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.closedate}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Description}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!mf}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!mp}" />
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize) < setCon.ResultSize}"
                             value="{!setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize} Of {!setCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize) >= setCon.ResultSize}"
                             value="{!setCon.ResultSize} Of {!setCon.ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setCon.hasNext}" value="Next" action="{!mn}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!setCon.hasNext}" value="Last" action="{!ml}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```